# Sort properties json without serializing to a model

Tags: c#, json, sorting, json.net

I have two json strings I want to compare.
The problem is that when the properties are the same but in a different order.

Simple example:

```
{
  "Number": "123",
  "Name": "My name",
  "FirstName": "My First name",
  "Prop1": false,
  "Prop2": [],
  "Plans": [],
  "SomeList": [
    {
      "Code": "118",
      "Period": {
        "From": "2000-01-27T00:00:00.0000000",
        "Until": "2003-12-31T00:00:00.0000000"
      }
    },
    {
      "Code": "120",
      "Period": {
        "From": "2004-01-01T00:00:00.0000000",
        "Until": "2004-12-31T00:00:00.0000000"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

and

```
{
  "Number": "123",
  "FirstName": "My First name",
  "Name": "My name",
  "Prop1": false,
  "Prop2": [],
  "Plans": [],
  "SomeList": [
    {
      "Code": "120",
      "Period": {
        "From": "2004-01-01T00:00:00.0000000",
        "Until": "2004-12-31T00:00:00.0000000"
      }
    },
    {
      "Code": "118",
      "Period": {
        "From": "2000-01-27T00:00:00.0000000",
        "Until": "2003-12-31T00:00:00.0000000"
      }
    }    
  ]
}
```

These two json's are equal.
The compare function JToken.DeepEquals says it's not equal.
And I don't want to serialize to an object XYZ to compare both jsons.
I want to sort the properties of the json so the JToken.DeepEquals works fine.

Comment: why do you want to know the order of the properties?

Comment: Show how you have defined "Period". They don't look like `strings`, and whether they are strings or not massively affect the answers you'll get.

Comment: if the order of the properties is the same, the JToken.DeepEquals works fine to compare the 2 jsons

Comment: If you're insistent on not serializing it or performing `DeepEquals` on `JObject`s then I'm afraid it can only be a case of splitting the String up into relevant parts, re-ordering them and then calling that method on the reodered `Strings`. Although, at that point, there's little advantage to using `DeepEquals` over a simple `for` loop and a series of `String.Compare`s.